# Oracle Database characterset migration from WE8MSWIN1252 to AL32UTF8

Tags: oracle, utf-8, oracle11g, special-characters, confluence

Our Confluence database have over 100 tables and it is over 3 GB large. In initial setup the database was created with default characterset (WE8MSWIN1252). But now we want unicode characters to display on Confluence and, so that we want our database characterset to be AL32UTF8.

But we don't want to lose any of the data because, it is in production environment. Our confluence 5.7.3 web application is supporting UTF-8 but database does not.

How can I converert the Database to AL32UTF8, without loosing any data?

Answer (score 0):

It involves a lot of checks and steps to change the **database characterset**. It is usually a one time activity and is done at database creation time. Now that you want to move to a different `NLS_CHARACTERSET`, it depends on a lot of factors.

There are several **Dos** and **DON'Ts** and prerequisites.

- Pre-Oracle `12c` version(precisely pre-`11.2.0.3`)

**CSSCAN** tool is a prerequisite.

- From Oracle `12c`(precisely `11.2.0.3` onwards)

**Database Migration Assistant for Unicode** (DMU) will be the only tool available to migrate to Unicode.

You must follow the steps mentioned in [MOS Doc ID 260192.1 - Changing the NLS_CHARACTERSET to AL32UTF8 / UTF8 (Unicode)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=mduxnq46j_4&_afrLoop=181754188636297#PURPOSE)